# how to set the language property value of app localization element by getting the value from browser?

Tags: javascript, localization, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using the https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-localize-behavior to implement localization.

I would like to see if we can automatically set the language value based out of the browser user agent setting for language. I believe we can set it up using JS, but would like to if polymer element provide this capability through some other setting. Thanks for your help !

```
properties: {
  language: {
    value: 'en'
  },
}
```

Comment: Are you using only two-character language locales? Or are you using country-specific language locales too?